# Using REGEXREPLACE() and VLOOKUP() to search and replace using a pairwise list

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have a list of people with unique first and last names, in two columns, B and C. [See example spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yCQR-lWUSPpIR3RG1kYMbOnuxzwMS9Ko7sbLnUtv0k8/edit#gid=0).

Cell `E6` contains the following text:

`Firstname1 would like to say hello to Firstname2. Firstname3 also says hello.`

I would like to write an in-cell formula (*i.e.*, not using custom functions) that goes through the text and replaces first names with the corresponding last names. The result should look like this:

`Lastname1 would like to say hello to Lastname2. Lastname3 also says hello.`

I tried the following, but it seems not to work:

`=REGEXREPLACE(E6,"(Firstname[0-9])",VLOOKUP("$1",B:C,2))`

Any ideas? It's important that the solution not use a custom formula.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need additoinally add a regexextract step:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"(Firstname[0-9])",VLOOKUP(regexextract( A1,"Firstname[0-9]"),B:C,2,false))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(E6," "),B:C,2,0),SPLIT(E6," "))))
```

- SPLIT E6 by space to give a array
- VLOOKUP the corresponding words in B:C
- IF #N/A, Use the SPLITted array
- JOIN back the modified array